# How to exclude 0 from count()? in sql?

Tags: sql, count, presto

I have a code as below where I want to count number of first purchases for a given period of time. I have a column in my sales table where if the buyer is not a first time buyer, then `is_first_purchase = 0`

For example:
`buyer_id = 456391` is already an existing buyer who made purchases on 2 different dates.
Hence `is_first_purchase` column will show as 0 as per below.

[image: Database column]

If i do a count() on is_first_purchase for this buyer_id = 456391 then it should return 0 instead of 2.

My query is as follows:

```
with first_purchases as 
    (select *,
    case when is_first_purchase = 1 then 'Yes'  else 'No' end as first_purchase
    from sales)
        
select 
    count(case when first_purchase = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as no_of_first_purchases 
from first_purchases 
where buyer_id = 456391 
    and date_id between '2021-02-01' and '2021-03-01' 
    order by 1 desc;
```

It returned the below which is not an intended output

[image: Result of query in db]

Appreciate if someone can help explain how to exclude is_first_purchase = 0 from the count, thanks.

Comment: Use `null` rather than 0. Null values are not counted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `COUNT` function count when the value isn't `NULL` (include 0), if you don't want to count, need to let `CASE WHEN` return `NULL`

There are two ways you can count as your expectation, one is `SUM` other is `COUNT` but remove the part of `else 0`

```
SUM(case when first_purchase = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as no_of_first_purchases 

COUNT(case when first_purchase = 'Yes' then 1 end) as no_of_first_purchases
```

From your question, I would combine `CTE` and main query as below

```
select 
    COUNT(case when is_first_purchase = 1 then 1 end) as no_of_first_purchases 
from sales 
where buyer_id = 456391 
and date_id between '2021-02-01' and '2021-03-01' 
order by 1 desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are using COUNT() when you want SUM().

```
    with first_purchases as 
(select *,
case when is_first_purchase = 1 then 'Yes'  else 'No' end as first_purchase
from sales)
    
    select 
SUM(case when first_purchase = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as no_of_first_purchases 
from first_purchases 
where buyer_id = 456391 
and date_id between '2021-02-01' and '2021-03-01' 
order by 1 desc;
```

You could simplify your query as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 
FROM  sales no_of_first_purchases
WHERE is_first_purchase = 1
AND buyer_id = 456391 
AND date_id  BETWEEN '2021-02-01' AND '2021-03-01' 
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

It is better to avoid the use of functions like IF and CASE when it can be done with WHERE.

Comment: this works! I was wondering why. if the value of is_first_purchase is NULL instead of 0, will count() do the same job as sum()? this is to clarify that count() does NOT count the # of rows in the records.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach for Trino (f.k.a. Presto SQL) is to use an [aggregate with a filter](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#filtering-during-aggregation):

```
count(name) FILTER (WHERE first_purchase = 'Yes') AS no_of_first_purchases
```